# How can I compile Cinder in Eclipse for MacOS X 10.8.2

Tags: eclipse, macos, linker, g++, cinder

I've downloaded and installed Cinder and even run the TinderBox tutorial to create a Cinder project in XCode.

However i'm keen to use eclipse as my IDE and not Xcode.

I'm running OSX 10.8.2

Having followed the following tutorials to configure eclipse [Configure Eclipse](http://ubiquisense.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=65%3acinder-eclipse-are-doing-it&catid=17%3alabs-category&Itemid=26) and [Vimeo Video](http://vimeo.com/19091388), I encountered a number of issues compiling and linking.

```
make *** Error 1 C/C++ Problem cinder
undefined symbols for architecture i386:
```

I figure i've either not followed the tutorial posts to the letter or there is some difference in my setup.

Note: this is a Question Answer post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**index**

1. Configure eclipse
2. Issues encountered and solutions
3. Appendix (source code)
4. References

** Configure eclipse **

*Assumes that you have a C++ version of eclipse and have created a basic C++ Cinder project.  You can find the .h and .cpp files in the appendix below. The following outlines the settings you need to configure to compile.*

**Step 1.**

1. Open the project 'properties' window.
2. Navigate to the C/C++ Build > 'Build Variables' option.

Add the following Variable.

```
CINDER_PATH /path/to/cinder_0.8.4_mac/
```

**Step 2.**

1. Navigate to the C/C++ Build > Settings window.
2. Under the Tools Tab select the 'MacOS X C++ Linker' option.

Here, in the 'command' input field you need to add after the g++ your command line options and OSX framework references

```
g++ -m32 -arch i386 -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit -framework Accelerate -framework AudioToolbox -framework AudioUnit -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreServices -framework QTKit -framework OpenGL -framework QuickTime -framework AppKit -framework Cocoa -framework CoreData -framework Foundation
```

*-m32* Tells the link to use 32 bit rather than 64 bit.

*-arch i386* Ensures we link for the correct architecture.

*-framework* Reference the frameworks required to run Cinder (As i understand it currently)

```
NOTE: Depending on your mac version you might find -framework Carbon in stead of -framework Cocoa, I used Cocoa.
```

**Step 3.**

1. Navigate to the 'MacOS X C++ Linker' > 'Libraries' option
2. Add the following library search paths. ( -L command line)

   ${CINDER_PATH}/lib
   ${CINDER_PATH}/lib/ios-sim
   ${CINDER_PATH}/lib/ios
   ${CINDER_PATH}/lib/macosx

Add the following libraries to include ( -l command line)

```
cinder
cinder_d
z
png14
pixman-1
cairo
boost_thread
boost_system
boost_filesystem
boost_date_time
cinder-iphone-sim_d
```

**Step 4.**

Under the 'MacOS X C++ Linker' menu select the 'Miscellaneous' option and add the following in the XLinker field.

```
${CINDER_PATH}/lib/libcinder_d.a

NOTE: It was adding this option along with the -arch i386 option that resolved this error "undefined symbols for architecture i386:"
```

**Step 5.**

1. Select the "GCC C++ Compiler" menu option.
2. Add the following in the 'command" field.

   g++ -m32 -arch i386

Select the 'Includes' menu option and add the following folder paths

```
${CINDER_PATH}/boost
${CINDER_PATH}/include
/System/Library/Frameworks
```

** Issues encountered and solutions **

**Problem A**

```
make *** Error 1 C/C++ Problem cinder
undefined symbols for architecture i386:
```

**Solution A**

I found that there were two contributing factors to overcoming this issue. The first was adding the -m32 and -arch i386 command line options to the linker and compiler settings.

The second was that inclusion of the following -XLinker option

```
${CINDER_PATH}/lib/libcinder_d.a
```

Note: The above is for debug mode, (The _d) for release you have to set it to

```
${CINDER_PATH}/lib/libcinder.a
```

** Appendix **

*HelloWorld.h*

```
#include "cinder/app/AppBasic.h"
#include "cinder/gl/gl.h"

using namespace ci;
using namespace ci::app;
using namespace std;


class HelloWorld : public AppBasic {
  public:
    void setup();
    void mouseDown( MouseEvent event );
    void update();
    void draw();
    void prepareSettings(Settings * settings);
};
```

*HellowWorld.cpp*

```
#include "HelloWorld.h"
// You dont' need this when you have the CINDER_APP_BASIC line below.
//int main(int argc, char **argv) {
//  return -1;
//}


void HelloWorld::setup()
{

}

void HelloWorld::mouseDown( MouseEvent event )
{
}

void HelloWorld::update()
{
}

void HelloWorld::draw()
{
    // clear out the window with black
    gl::clear( Color( 0, 0, 0 ) );
}

void HelloWorld::prepareSettings(Settings * settings)
{
    settings->setWindowSize( 800, 600 );
    settings->setFrameRate( 60.0f );
}

CINDER_APP_BASIC( HelloWorld, RendererGl )
```

**References**

All credit goes to these posts that helped me in the first place and of course the creators of Cinder.

1. [Original Tutorial followed to configure eclipse for Cinder](http://ubiquisense.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=65%3acinder-eclipse-are-doing-it&catid=17%3alabs-category&Itemid=26)
2. [Link that helped solve the problem of correctly linking](https://forum.libcinder.org/topic/cinder-eclipse-osx)